# how to grab through object, in order to grab all vertices in Wireframe mode?

Tags: sculpt

I am trying to move all the vertices in Sculpt mode with the Grab tool, but only the vertices in the front view are moving, I would like to move all vertices through the object, as we can do with the "C" shortcut in Wireframe mode. Would you know how to do this?

I created a circle, solidified it, move to the "3" view, Sculpt mode, and Grab.

I also remember an option to select vertices close to the one we selected, and move all the closest vertices, but I don't find it with the new version of Blender?

[image]

Comment: I would recommend using proportional editing, press O to activate, there are more options available if you click the button on the far right of the section at the top of your screen that says "Global".

Comment: ok thanks @Jakemoyo